# Pandas - Add mean, max, min as columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df =`

```
         statistics  s_values
year
1999  cigarette use       100
1999  cellphone use       310
1999   internet use       101
1999    alcohol use       100
1999       soda use       215
2000  cigarette use       315
2000  cellphone use       317
2000   internet use       325
2000    alcohol use       108
2000       soda use       200
2001  cigarette use       122
2001  cellphone use       311
2001   internet use       112
2001    alcohol use       144
2001       soda use       689
```

I calculated the max, min and mean based on the `year` `index` and `statistics` `column`.

I want to insert the mean, max and min as columns in the data frame where the output result looks like this

my desired output:

```
         statistics   s_values        mean  min     max
year                    
1999    alcohol use     100.0        104.0  100.0   108.0
1999    cellphone use   310.0        313.5  310.0   317.0
1999    cigarette use   100.0        207.5  100.0   315.0
1999    internet use    101.0        213.0  101.0   325.0
1999    soda use        215.0        207.5  200.0   215.0
2000    alcohol use     108.0        104.0  100.0   108.0
2000    cellphone use   317.0        313.5  310.0   317.0
2000    cigarette use   315.0        207.5  100.0   315.0
2000    internet use    325.0        213.0  101.0   325.0
2000    soda use        200.0        207.5  200.0   215.0
2001    alcohol use     144.0        104.0  100.0   108.0
2001    cellphone use   311.0        313.5  310.0   317.0
2001    cigarette use   122.0        207.5  100.0   315.0
2001    internet use    112.0        213.0  101.0   325.0
2001    soda use        689.0        207.5  200.0   215.0
```

I tried to do the following but values in the columns  are all `NaN`

```
gen_mean = df.groupby('statistics').mean()
gen_min = df.groupby('statistics').min()
gen_max = df.groupby('statistics').max()

df.insert(2, 'Gen Avg', gen_mean)
df.insert(3, 'Gen Max', gen_max)
df.insert(4, 'Gen Min', gen_min)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) + [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join):

```
df = df.join(
    df.groupby('statistics')['s_values'].aggregate(['mean', 'min', 'max']),
    on='statistics'
)
```

`df`:

```
         statistics  s_values        mean  min  max
year                                               
1999  cigarette use       100  179.000000  100  315
1999  cellphone use       310  312.666667  310  317
1999   internet use       101  179.333333  101  325
1999    alcohol use       100  117.333333  100  144
1999       soda use       215  368.000000  200  689
2000  cigarette use       315  179.000000  100  315
2000  cellphone use       317  312.666667  310  317
2000   internet use       325  179.333333  101  325
2000    alcohol use       108  117.333333  100  144
2000       soda use       200  368.000000  200  689
2001  cigarette use       122  179.000000  100  315
2001  cellphone use       311  312.666667  310  317
2001   internet use       112  179.333333  101  325
2001    alcohol use       144  117.333333  100  144
2001       soda use       689  368.000000  200  689
```

---

Frame Used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001,
             2001, 2001, 2001, 2001],
    'statistics': ['cigarette use', 'cellphone use', 'internet use',
                   'alcohol use', 'soda use',
                   'cigarette use', 'cellphone use', 'internet use',
                   'alcohol use', 'soda use',
                   'cigarette use', 'cellphone use', 'internet use',
                   'alcohol use', 'soda use'],
    's_values': [100, 310, 101, 100, 215, 315, 317, 325, 108, 200, 122, 311,
                 112, 144, 689]
}).set_index('year')
```

Answer (score 3):

`groupby(...).mean()` will return a dataframe with rows corresponding to groups. You need `transform`:

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('statistics')['s_values'].transform('mean')
# I hope you get the idea how to get min/max
```